# Lost join when self-joining a table on the same field

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a query that in SQL Server Management Studio would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    distinct(r2.code) AS code
    FROM  (SELECT 
    vMatrix.type AS type, 
    vMatrix.code AS code, 
    vMatrix.id AS id
    FROM vMatrix AS vMatrix) AS Extent1
    INNER JOIN DE_Scratch AS Extent2 ON (Extent1.code = Extent2.Code) AND (Extent1.type = Extent2.Type)
    INNER JOIN vMatrix as r2 ON Extent1.id = r2.id
    WHERE (Extent2.HeaderID = 94 and r2.type = 4)
```

Basically I have a table called `vMatrix` and I first join it with another table called `DE_Scratch` to select all the records from `vMatrix` that match `Code` and `Type` with `DE_Scratch`. So far, so good. Then I need to join that result with `vMatrix` again, this time matching up the `id` fields to select all the records in `vMatrix` that match the `id`s from the last join and then I just filter it by `type`.

I've been trying desperately to make this work in a LINQ statement, but it keeps losing the second join and basically returning me only the result from the first join (if I remove the `type` filter - else it returns nothing). For example:

```
var stuff = (from r1 in ctx.vMatrices
               join sr in ctx.DE_Scratch.Where(t => t.HeaderID == header.ID)
               on new { c = r1.code, t = r1.type } equals new { c = sr.Code, t = sr.Type }
               join r2 in ctx.vMatrices
               on r1.id equals r2.id into tmp
               from t in tmp where t.region_type == filterType
               select t.code).Distinct().ToList();
```

And variations of this with and without the `into` clause, with the order of joins rearranged, etc all consistently give me an actual query with just the one join. It seems it won't do the self-join on the table for some unknown reason.

What am I missing here?

My guess is that it's looking at the `id == id` part and deciding that it can optimize that join away, but it can't. The SQL generated is basically the same as my SQL statement minus the second join. There is no second `inner join` and no clause matching `id = id`. How can I force it to not ignore that join?

For example this:

```
var stuff = (from r2 in ctx.vMatrices
           join r1 in (from t in ctx.vMatrices
                       join sr in ctx.DE_Scratch.Where(t => t.HeaderID == header.ID)
                       on new { c = t.code, t = t.type } equals new { c = Code, t = Type }
                       select t.id)
           on r2.id equals r1 
           select r2).ToList();
```

Generates this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[type] AS [type], 
    [Extent1].[code] AS [code], 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id]
    FROM  (SELECT 
    [vRegionMatrix].[type] AS [type], 
    [vRegionMatrix].[code] AS [code], 
    [vRegionMatrix].[id] AS [id]
    FROM [dbo].[vMatrix] AS [vMatrix]) AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DE_Scratch] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[type] = [Extent2].[Type]) AND ([Extent1].[code] = [Extent2].[Code])
    WHERE ([Extent2].[HeaderID] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
```

**UPDATE**: This is about as far as I have got:

```
var regions = (from r1 in
                   (from t in ctx.vMatrices
                    join sr in ctx.DE_Scratch.Where(t => t.HeaderID == header.ID)
                    on new { c = t.code, t = t.type.Value } equals new { c = sr.Code, t = sr.Type }
                    select t.id)
               join r2 in ctx.vMatrices.GroupBy(c => c.id)
               on r1 equals r2.Key
                   select (int?)r2.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(l => l.type == filterType).FirstOrDefault().code).Distinct().ToList();
```

This *almost* works. The problem is that in some case the grouping will have more than one entry so by using `FirstOrDefault()` I lose some of the results. What I need is equivalent to a `SelectMany` to flatten the results of the group, but when I tried removing that last line and replacing it with another `from...in`:

```
from f in r2.DefaultIfEmpty()
where f.type == filterType
select f.code).Distinct().ToList();
```

I suddenly lose that last join again and end up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your second INNER JOIN you are referring to Extend1 which you already manipulated with your first INNER JOIN before. You may try something like

```
SELECT 
distinct(r2.code) AS code
FROM  ((SELECT 
vMatrix.type AS type, 
vMatrix.code AS code, 
vMatrix.id AS id
FROM vMatrix AS vMatrix) AS Extent1
INNER JOIN DE_Scratch AS Extent2 ON (Extent1.code = Extent2.Code) 
AND (Extent1.type = Extent2.Type)) AS Extend3
INNER JOIN vMatrix as r2 ON Extent3.id = r2.id
WHERE (Extent2.HeaderID = 94 and r2.type = 4)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question isn't about the SQL *per se*, I know how to write SQL that will give me the results I want (see the first one). What I'm trying to figure out is how to convince LINQ to entities to *generate* that (or equivalent) SQL from a linq statement. But for some reason it seems it wants to ignore the second join.